# python - Convert Single integer into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Say I have the following lists:

```
a = 1
b = [2,3]
c = [4,5,6]
```

I want to concatenate them such that I get the following:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I tried the usual `+` operator:

```
>>> a+b+c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

This is because of the `a` term. It is just an integer. So I convert everything to a list:

```
>>> [a]+[b]+[c]
[1, [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Not quite what I'm looking for.

I also tried all the options in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python), but I get the same `int` error mentioned above.

```
>>> l = [a]+[b]+[c]
>>> flat_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

It should be simple enough, but nothing works with that term `a`. Is there any way to do this **efficiently**? It doens't necessarily have to be *pythonic*.

Comment: Question: why do you have inconsistent data types in the first place? Why not use lists consistently for all the variables?

Comment: My problem wasn't this simple. It was a part of a function where I updated the values of a list constantly (list of lists with variable lengths). It would be messy had I written it all here. But this was by basic error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's nothing that will automatically treat an `int` as if it's a list of one `int`. You need to check whether the value is a list or not:

```
(a if type(a) is list else [a]) + (b if type(b) is list else [b]) + (c if type(c) is list else [c])
```

If you have to do this often you might want to write a function:

```
def as_list(x):
    if type(x) is list:
        return x
    else:
        return [x]
```

Then you can write:

```
as_list(a) + as_list(b) + as_list(c)
```

Comment: I was actually running `a+b+c` for lists that change sizes. I only considered `a`. But at some point, even c became 1 integer. Got that from your function. Thanks

Comment: Are you going to fix the question to have the correct value of `a`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools`:

```
from itertools import chain

a = 1
b = [2,3]
c = [4,5,6]
final_list = list(chain.from_iterable([[a], b, c]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

However, if you do not know the contents of `a`, `b`, and `c` ahead of time, you can try this:

```
new_list = [[i] if not isinstance(i, list) else i for i in [a, b, c]]
final_list = list(chain.from_iterable(new_list))
```

Comment: Will this work with `a = 1`, which is apparently his real situation?

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is the best way. Adding another variation. Explanation in comments as well.

```
from collections.abc import Iterable


a = "fun" 
b = [2,3]
c = [4,5,6]


def flatten(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item,Iterable) and not isinstance(item,str): # checking if Iterable and taking care of strings as well
            yield from flatten(item)
        else:
            yield item

# test case:

res = []
res.extend([a]+[b]+[c]) # casting them into lists,  [a]+[b]+[c] [1, [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
print(list(flatten(res)))
```

Produces

```
['fun', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

[Program finished]
```